# Encapsulating services in a plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I get the idea in Grails Services from a plugin can be injected into applications that use that plugin.  But, what if don't want some services to be injectable, you only want the plugin to know about them.

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "you only want the plugin to know about them"? Could you please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using pluginExcludes property in *GrailsPlugin.groovy script:

```
  def pluginExcludes = [
      "grails-app/services/com/my/package/MyService.groovy",           
  ]
```

This way the service won't be included into packed plugin *.zip file.

One drawback is that this approach does not work for in-place plugins - see http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-5404

In-place plugins are the ones that are loaded from file system using the path specified:

```
grails.plugin.location.shiro = "/home/dilbert/dev/plugins/grails-shiro"
```

Comment: Won't this actually exclude it from being included in the plugin entirely? Meaning it won't be available to the plugin itself either?

Answer (score 0):

All Grails services are exposed as Spring beans. These beans are available through the application context, and thus the containing application that uses the plugin. There really isn't a way to 'protect' these services from being used.